# Determining the bounds for a triple integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus, volume

I need help with a triple integration problem. I don't need help actually integrating this thing, I just need help with setting the actual integral(s) up. Specifically, I dont know how to determine what the bounds are.

We basically have a 3D donut. The problem says we can model the donut as a torus centered at the origin (0,0,0) with outer radius R=4 and inner radius r=2. The points (x,y,z) inside the torus are described by the following condition:

[Equation Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnfky.png)

Here, *c* is the radius from the origin to the center of the torus tube (so I think it's 3), and *a* is the radius of the donut tube (so I think it should be 1), the cross section of the donut tube is a circle.

I need to calculate the volume of the donute after 2 cuts. The first cut happens parallel to the x axis at y = -3, and then parallel to the y axis at x = 1.

So far, I set up the following integral (in polar coordinates) that I *think* represents the volume of the whole donut:

[Integral Eq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWayp.png)

But I dont know how to subtract the cuts? I'm assuming I need two more integrals that have to be subtracted from the whole volume, but I cant set it up. Can anyone help? Is the volume I have correct so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem of order: The limits on the $z$ integral depend on $r$, and therefore it has to be done where $r$ is defined. In other words, the integral is $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_2^4\int_{-\sqrt{a^2-(r-c)^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2-(r-c)^2}} rdzdrd\theta$$

And you are correct that $c = 3$ and $a = 1$

But as noted in the comments, this approach does not work well with the cuts. The problem is, the cuts are flat, which leads to complicated limits of integration for $r$ and/or $\theta$, which will undo the advantages of going to cylindrical representation ("polar" coordinates are in the plane - the 3D analogs are either "cylindrical", as you are using here, or "spherical").

Let's look at the cuts. The first is by the plane $y = -3$ (which is automatically parallel to the x-axis and to the z-axis). This plane is tangent to the "center ring" of the torus. The other plane is $x = 1$, which passes through the hole. Note that these two planes meet inside the torus. To set the up as an integral in $x, y, z$, you need to consider that for given values of $x$, there are in general two separate ranges of values for $y$ that need integrated over, and vice versa. The way to handle this is to break the torus up into quadrants and work each quadrant separately. Within each quadrant, there is only one range for $x$ or $y$ to be integrated. We can also do the same for $z$, limiting attention to $z \le 0$ and $z \ge 0$ separately. But in this case, the geometry is symmetric, so we will pick up the same volume on either side. Thus we can calculate only $z \ge 0$, then double it to get the whole volume.

The equation of the torus surface is $$z^2 +(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - 3)^2 = 1$$ So we can set up the integration over the entire first quadrant as
$$2\int_0^4\int_0^{\sqrt{16 - x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-3)^2}} dzdydx$$

After cutting, for each quadrant we have:

- Quadrant 1: $0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y$

$$2\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{16 - x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-3)^2}} dzdydx$$

- Quadrant 2: $x \le 0, 0 \le y$

$$2\int_{-4}^0\int_0^{\sqrt{16 - x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-3)^2}} dzdydx$$

- Quadrant 3: $x \le 0, -3 \le y \le 0$

$$2\int_{-4}^0\int_{-3}^{\sqrt{4 - x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-3)^2}} dzdydx$$

- Quadrant 4: $0 \le x \le 1, -3 \le y \le 0$

$$2\int_0^1\int_{-3}^{\sqrt{4 - x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-3)^2}} dzdydx$$

The $z$ integration is easy, but for the $y$ and $x$ integrations, you will need some trigonmetric substitutions.

Comment: OK. If the integral you have above describes the volume of the entire donut, then I still need to calculate how much of the donut is left after 2 pieces are removed. The first piece removed is parallel to the x axis at y = -3, and the second is parallel to the y axis at x = 1. Does that make sense?

Comment: Your "cuts" are defined in terms of $x$ and $y$, so you have two choices: rewrite your integral in terms of x-y-z, or figure out how the cuts can be defined in terms of $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: @JohnAlberto - I posted this late at night before I went to bed. I'm sorry that I somehow failed to notice that you had described the cuts. Apparently I skipped right over that paragraph without noticing it. I'll correct my post later when I have more time. nukeguy is right - with those cuts you will wnat to express the integration in terms of $x, y, z$, or possibly get the full volume from this integral, then express the cuts in terms of $x, y, z$.

Comment: Thanks nukeguy and Paul. I do understand that it might be more straightforward to just solve this in terms of x and y, however I havent been able to figure it out. To express the cuts in polar coordinates I think I need to use the equations x=pcos(theta) and y=psin(theta) but I havent been able to make sense of these graphically.

Comment: @JohnAlberto - I've updated my answer with a discussion on how to set up the integral for $x, y, z$.